# Hadoop Spark - Store in one Large File instead of Many Small ones and Index

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-partitioning

On a daily basis i would be calculating some stats and storing it in a file (about 40 rows of data). df below is calculated daily. The issue is when i store it each day it becomes a new file and i do not want to do this as hadoop doesn't deal well with multiple small files. I cannot overrride the file as i need the historic data as well.

1. How do i make one large file every day - i.e i write to the same master file instead of writing to a new file daily.
2. I know you can use coalese(1) i think but ive read this is has poor performance so i do not know?
3. I want to index this file by a time column within the file. How do i achieve this?

   ```
   df.repartition(1).write.save(mypath, format='parquet',mode='append', header='true')
   ```

Comment: 40 rows of data is still small. Are you sure you need Hadoop for storing this?

Comment: Probably not. But i have the rest of the data in hadoop so I still have not figured out how to keep them in separate locations and still use within the same problem easily. If you have any reference architecture I would be happy to read up :) The issue is I am storing stats at micro seconds, seconds and 1 hour. The one hour file is very small however, microseconds file is large so probably need hadoop. So i wanted to keep it in the same file system without using another DB for this. Hence the question

Answer (score 0):

You can override same old file daily by doing this.
DF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)

Comment: I cannot override the file as i need the data in the old file as well. So on day 1 i will have 40 data points, on day two I have another 40 data points however it needs to be appended to the main file (40 + 40 = 80 data points)

Comment: @Secret you can `df.partitonBy("datetime").write...` to get partitioned folders

Comment: @cricket_007 : Thank you. I do want to not partition it but write it in one large file if that makes sense. So on a daily basis i would be appending to the same master file instead of multiple folders for each day? Hence partition by will not work

Comment: @SecretAgent No, if you partition by a day folder, then you would be creating and overwriting just that date folder. For example, `data/day=20180530`, then the following day with `data/day=20180531`

Comment: @cricket_007 : Thank you. I am currently doing something similar. But i guess what i want to be doing is appending to the same file. If i do the above i may have several days with files that have around 30 rows of data which isn't going to be very efficient.